# Lots of error 404 from crawlers and bots

Tags: wordpress, seo

Im getting a lot of error 404 from crawlers according to Wordpress wordfence.  [Here's the screenshot from Wordpress Wordfence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IX14.png)

```
"GET /poloralphlauren/?france=basket+ralph+lauren+pas+cher HTTP/1.0" 503 521 "http://www.website1.com/"
"GET /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 33285 "http://www.website1.com/poloralphlauren/?france=basket+ralph+lauren+pas+cher"
```

They also keep showing in Google webmasters. [Here's the screenshot from Google Webmasters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vmaH.png)

I've already done the following:

1. disabled all the plugins and changed themes
2. deleted the entire Wordpress and re-installed Wordpress
3. terminated the entire cPaneL account and created a new cPaneL account.
4. searched html codes, php files, phpmyadmin, grep -ir using SSH for `poloralphlauren`
5. installed wordfence plugin to scan files for malware, but there's no malware.

The website is about travel, not about apparel. Why do I get a lot of search queries like `poloralphlauren` that's not entirely related to the website? Do these errors affect website ranking?

Comment: Please edit your question: What exactly are you trying to do? What error/s did you encounter? What are you working with?

Comment: The website is about travel, not about apparel. Why do I get a lot of search queries like `poloralphlauren` that's not entirely related to the website? Do these errors affect website ranking?

Comment: Did you check your robots.txt? My guess would be that you have those links in there.

Answer (score 2):

Have you recently created that website or have you recently installed or tried a new Wordpress theme on your website? There are couple of possibilities:

1. In the past, you had a page or post with that name & URL.
2. You tried a theme that had some sample pages or posts.
3. Some other website is linking to your website for this URL. If anyone clicks on that link or any crawler visits that link it will generate these 404 errors mentioned by you

Also, your screenshot from google webmaster tool suggests that these pages were part of your website in the past. However, these pages do not exist now. That's why google is getting 404.

Generally, 404 errors like that are not bad for website ranking, but it's better if you figure out the reason of these errors. It will be bad for website ranking only if these errors are too frequent, or are due to someone injecting bad code into your website pages through malware or hacking.